# iTunes Connect Test Flight - Different build number, same version number - Not showing up in tester's devices

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

There are lots of extremely similar posts but I'm not sure if there are any exactly like this.

I changed the build number but kept the version the same. I uploaded it and now it shows two builds in iTunes Connect's app prerelease builds as expected. But on my internal testers' devices, it doesn't show any updates.

It's been a few hours now and still no change.

Comment: Ensure you add the tester device in your profile.. If not means add the device in your profile release it again.. And also ask the tester to check the app show in "InCompatible app"

Comment: Keep Build number and Version number in sync.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue.  If you turn off beta testing in iTunes Connect and turn it back on again, the builds in the TestFlight app will update, and users will get the notification.  This way you don't need to change the version number.

Comment: Ah yes, I figured this out myself anyway. Thanks for the answer though. I'll mark you as correct

Answer (score -2):

Change build number and version number both to update build on iTunes Connect's .

Comment: Sometimes I want the testers to test what i have so far, not the whole version if I havent done it. Also since I can change just the version number for it to update, why both changing the build number?

Comment: else you can check tester device profile certificates.

Comment: I didnt make any profiles for them manually, test flight does it for me doesn't it? And what do you mean check?

Comment: Also I did try changing the build and version number in another update but it didn't show up